# Chrome 44: Switch back to previous profile management

Tags: google-chrome

In the past Google introduced a new way of switching users in Chrome browser. Now it is located on the right side of the the window:

[image: New chrome user switcher]

I strongly prefer the previous way of switching users on the top left corner of Chrome:

[image: Previous Chrome user switcher]

When they have introduced this new feature, I was able to disable it using this option under `chrome://flags`: **#enable-new-profile-management**

[image: Chrome Flags: #enable-new-profile-management]

The value of this flag seems to be ignored in general since the update to Chrome 44. So has the previous user switcher has been removed entirely? Or is there another trick existing, to disable the "new profile management".

Comment: you can right click the name on top right corner & switch.

Comment: Yes, thanks. I figured this already out. But at work I am always working with two profiles. One work, one private profile. Now I have to read the text in the right corner instead of regognizing the icon in the left. I liked the icon in the left very much more! And furthermore I don't see any benefits of this "new profile manager".

Answer (score 1):

I agree - the change appears to have no benefit, and is cumbersome. Is there a keyboard shortcut to quickly switch ?

I used to be able to CMD+Shift+M, press up/down, and hit enter to switch users. Now the same keyboard shortcut takes twice as many keys (CMD+Shift+M, press down to "Switch Person", Enter, press right twice, hit enter). Frustrating!

Comment: Indeed! At least it takes not more clicks, when using the right mouse key. The question for me is: What is the bug? That old profile management is not appearing or that the chrome://flags page still contains the option to disable the new profile manager. I guess it's the last one.